# Problem with translation in ASP.NET Core via ASP.NET Core localization in _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, asp.net-core-mvc, translate

I am trying to learn programming in ASP.NET Core by making simple programs, but I got stuck with translating some parts of texts by using a localization feature.
For example, I created Resources and folders with all needed resource files with translated words and phrases. For _Layout.cshtml i created Resources -> Views -> Shared -> _Layout.en.resx and _Layout.fr.resx

I tried to use this type of code but it doesn't work, the page is loading but when I change the culture from en to fr the words in _Layout don't change, only what I get is the words write in @localizer quotes in both languages.

The code in _Layout is the same as yours.

The differences in Startup.cs:

In ConfigureServices:

services.AddLocalization(opt => { opt.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix).AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

```
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
            opt =>
            {
                var supportCulteres = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr")
                };
                opt.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
                opt.SupportedCultures = supportCulteres;
                opt.SupportedUICultures = supportCulteres;
            });
```

In Configure i add only that code:
app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions>().Value);

I made this to work this file _Culture.cshtml (problem with adding code)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WV9pn.jpg

And I got side like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vRWE.jpg
And after changing the language (in this example i have polish language but normally it is french)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbn8j.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a whole working demo:

1.Add resource file in `Resources/Views/Shared` folder in root project:

[image]

2.Edit your resource file(`_Layout.fr.resx`) like below:

**Note**:Be sure you have added the correct value for key(`Home`,`Privacy`,`Book List`.Book List contains **space**).

[image]

3.Create `_Culture.cshtml`:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions

@{
    var culture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureList = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}

<div>
    <form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="CultureManagement"
          asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl" method="post">
        <select name="culture" asp-for="@culture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureList"
                onchange="this.form.submit();" >
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

4.Change your `_Layout.cshtml` like below:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization.IViewLocalizer localizer

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    //...
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MvcCore3_1</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">@localizer["Home"]</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">@localizer["Privacy"]</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    //add the partial here
                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_Culture")
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2020 - MvcCore3_1 - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

5.Be sure add `AddViewLocalization` in your Startup.cs like below:

**Note:** It should be:`app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>()` not `app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions>()`.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);

        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
         opt =>
         {
             var supportCulteres = new List<CultureInfo>
             {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("fr")
             };
             opt.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
             opt.SupportedCultures = supportCulteres;
             opt.SupportedUICultures = supportCulteres;
         });

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
        app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);
        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {               
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 
        });

    }
```

6.Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CultureManagement(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }
    );

    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I have this code in my Startup.cs and it is working but only for Views/Home/Index.cshtml and Privacy.cshtml for example. I want to translate the words Home and Privacy next to your MvcCore3_1.

Comment: I have _Layout and Resources files like you, however my Startup code is a little different because I created _Culture file which present button with language choice to prevent writing '?culture=en/fr' (I add screenshots)

Comment: Hi @MarkKrupp,I have updated the answer and provide the whole code.Still working fine in my project.Please be sure your resource file added the correct key and value.The key should be the same with `Home`,`Privacy` and `Book List`.The letter case and the space in letter.All of them should keep the same.

Comment: Great! It is working! I think that problem was in Startup.cs. Thank you so much for your help and time. As a new user I am truly shocked how fast and helpful this community is